# Create a pivot table

Tags: jasper-reports

I have the below excel data(and it is my backend)

```
  Date      Editor  Units
7/1/2013    Amreen  158
7/2/2013    Amreen  23
7/3/2013    Amreen  1
7/6/2013    Amreen  33
7/3/2013    Amreen  77
7/3/2013    Amreen  66
7/3/2013    Anirudh 748
7/3/2013    Amreen  8
7/6/2013    Amreen  402
7/7/2013    Amreen  24
7/7/2013    Amreen  146
7/9/2013    Amreen  33
7/8/2013    Amreen  45
7/8/2013    Amreen  21
```

I want to create a pivot table using *JasperReports*. I'm new to this technology or framework(i'm not sure of what it is to be said as), can anybody help me to get the table in the below format with explanation. I'm really confused and unable to understand how to do it.

```
          Amreen    Anirudh Anand   Total
7/1/2013    158                      158
7/2/2013    23                        23
7/3/2013    152      748             900
7/4/2013                
7/5/2013                
7/6/2013    435                      435
7/7/2013    170                      170
7/8/2013    66                        66
7/9/2013    33               33       66
Total      1037      748     33     1818
```

if not the solution please give me a reference of this type of instances (Excel and *JasperReports* pivot).

Comment: You can use [Crosstabs](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/crosstabs/index.html#crosstabs)

Comment: Hi @AlexK Thanks for respondinng, i'm unable to understand how to do it. Can you please provide any sample as there, there are some xml type files. Thanks

Comment: Did you see the link?

Comment: Yes i did but i was unable to understand it.

Comment: You can read this guide: [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cross table,  with Edit in Column and Date in Row and Unit as sum in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Crosstab from the Palette. First create a datasource for you report which can be excel or any RDBMS. Then when you drag and drop the Crosstab from the palette a wizard will open. Just follow the wizard and your Pivot table will be done in no time. I hope this helps. For more info [link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/tutorial-creating-pivot-table-ireport-designer)

Comment: A link-only answers are not acceptable here - links get broken. Please elaborate your answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @yakobom. I just edited my answer